# Package java class

Tags: java, jar, package, embedded-resource, executable-jar

I built a small program that displays the contents of a text file in the src folder of the package, in this case, it displays pi to a million decimal places. [(code)](https://gist.github.com/vedantchan/6657483)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class piMillion
{
    public void method() throws IOException
    {
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("src/pi.txt"));
        boolean rem = fileIn.hasNext();
        while (rem==true)
        {
            String line = fileIn.nextLine();
            System.out.println (line);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I package the program so that it runs independently, and displays the output in a new window?

Comment: Do you use any IDE or just console??

Comment: I use Sublime Text to write my code, and test it using BlueJ.

Comment: I have not worked with BlueJ. But what problem are you facing?? Can't you export your code to a jar??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The class and text file needs to be put in a *runnable Jar*.  For details, see:

   1. [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)
   2. [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).
2. To fulfill the 'entry point' requirements it will need a method with signature:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   ```
3. This line needs to change from `File` to `URL` in order to work for an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).

   ```
   Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("src/pi.txt"));
   ```

   See the [info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for details on how to form the URL.
4. `System.out.println (line);`  The output of `System.out` is not seen for a runnable Jar.  It will need a GUI.  See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for further details.

Comment: See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  You might notice that it is a Trail as opposed to a Lesson or simply a page.  That is a hint of the complexity of setting up a GUI.